# Where do I set order status based on order details after authorization in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7, payment-gateway

As an added fraud control I would like to set different order statuses based off of certain order details after a customer places an order.

Something like:

```
if($order->getPayment()->getTransaction()->getAdditionalInformation('avszip') != Y)
  $order->setState('review for fraud');
else
  $order->setState('processing');
```

Where would I do this? I assume I would intercept some default setState line of code in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php
```

Comment: Did you know there is a Magento SE site? Currently in beta: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a observer for `sales_order_place_after` or `sales_order_payment_place_end`

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <fraudtracking>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>fraudtracking/observer</class>
                <method>changestatus</method>
            </fraudtracking>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
```

In your observer.php

```
//Create a new status in Admin -> System -> Order Statuses
$STATE = 'fraud';

$_order = $event->getOrder();
if($order->getPayment()->getTransaction()->getAdditionalInformation('avszip') != Y){
    $_order->addStatusHistoryComment('Review for fraud', $STATE)
                   ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                   ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
}
```